# In magento How to add any numbers of custom input field on product page front-end in 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9

User can add any number of fields form frontend **product view page**.

There is a button to **add more field**. which user can **add text and submit**. Client wants to sale their mugs and each mug they want to save different message if they want.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that goal you have to use custom code, since Magento doesn't provide the functionality to do it via admin panel.

You will need to create a little module that adds the attribute and renders the input. There is an article that explains it: http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-magento-attribute-with-custom-input-renderer/